# Как в Delphi 7  использовать PHP скрипты?

Tags: delphi, php

Советы, примеры и ссылки рассматриваются...

Comment: Наверняка супер бот или продвинутый троян.<img src="/vote/20648/up/" width="1px"/>

Comment: Не, я так понял, что суть именно в использовании php в качестве скриптового языка внутри delphi-приложения.

Comment: Например клиент - сервер. php для работы над информацией на серввере из дельфи.

Answer (score 1):

Тогда вопрос должен звучать: "Как на делфи работать с HTTP". Потому что при подключении к web-серверу клиенту совершенно не важно PHP там или нет.

Используйте компонент idHTTP из стандартного пакета.